# How to find if a 3d point is inside the same surface as a 3d triangle

Tags: geometry

Imagine that we have a triangle where each point is represented using 3 coordinates. How can we tell if a point, which is also represented using 3 coordinates, isn't inside the triangle, but is on the same surface as the triangle ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on https://math.stackexchange.com/ or be reformulated into a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Having triangle points `A, B, C`, we can build vectors

```
AB = B - A
AC = C - A
```

and normal vector `N` using cross product

```
N = AB x AC
```

To check whether point P belongs to ABC plane, calculate dot product

```
AP = P - A
dp = AP.dot.N
```

`dp` is equal to zero for points in the plane (use some tolerance to compensate numerical errors)

To find whether point is outside triangle:
choose any non-zero component of normal `N` (say z-component)
calculate only this component of cross-product of

```
AB x AP  (here we need only (AB.x*AP.y-AB.y*AP.x) to get z-component of result)
BC x BP
CA x CP
```

If all signs of results are equal (positive or negative) - `P` is inside, if signs differ - `P` is outside.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if the points distance to the plane is zero.

Here is my first google hit https://mathinsight.org/distance_point_plane